# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord order query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I was wondering if someone could help me with this one.

My question is regarding the order method in rails. My goal is to order the DB table according to weekprice (starting with the smallest value/price) and then query those first records to calculate the final price. For some reason the order method doesn't work because instead of giving me the Hotel.first.weekprice according to the performed order (smallest price first) it still uses the primary key and gives me just the first entry of weekprice in the table.

```
<% if Hotel.minimum(:weekprice) >  Hotel.minimum(:weekendprice) %>
<% Hotel.order(weekprice: :asc) %>
<%= Hotel.first.weekprice + Hotel.first.weekendprice %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your view code seems to contain a lot of database queries which seems unusual, you should fetch your `Hotel` objects inside of your `Controller`-method and assign it to an instance variable you then use to display whatever you like about the `Hotel`s in your view. I do not quite understand what your first line should do, as it will query the whole table (or at least your scope). It will not reduce the number of hotels you get from your table. Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: if i try it like this it raises an error saying 'Direction should be :asc or :desc'

Comment: what I want to achieve is basically finding the cheapest weekprice available for Hotel X and then take the corresponding weekendprice to calculate the final price. My problem was/or is, that I can easily get the cheapest weekprice (like Hotel.minimum(:weekprice)) but I dont know how to get the weekendprice for the same hotel - so I thought I order then just take all the records from the first row?

Comment: Hey patru, thx for the help. Unfortunately the second query also returns an error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hotel.order(weekprice: :asc)` will not order the table, it will order that query, I think what you want is something like:

```
Hotel.order(weekprice: :asc).first
```

as this will give you the first of the Hotel's ordered by weekprice, otherwise you are calling the method on the class again which has not changed or been ordered.

Comment: the problem is when i calculate Hotel.first.weekprice + Hotel.first.weekendprice for the output it doesnt work. So what you saying is instead of doing this I should rather do something like: Hotel.order(weekprice: :asc).first + Hotel.order(weekendprice: :asc).first for the final price?

Comment: yes, read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering and the whole guide to understand ordering.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in the end:

```
        <% price = Hotel.order(weekprice: :asc).first %>
        <%= price.weekprice + price.weekendprice %>
```

thank you guys very much.